# Remove options select with a value greater than 0

Tags: jquery

I would to remove all the options (but the first one with value = 0) from a select with id="myid".

I wouldn't to use empty() and then append().

Comment: You can use `.filter` or `.slice` and `.remove`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/, http://api.jquery.com/slice/, http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it is the first element, use gt and remove

```
$("#myid option:gt(0)").remove();
```

use attribute selector

```
$('#myid option[value!="0"]').remove();
```

use filter

```
$('#myid option').filter(
    function () {
        return parseInt(this.value,10) !== 0; 
    }
);
```